# $\overline{\mu}(E) = 0$ iff there is $(A_n) \subset \mathscr{A}$ s.t. $E \subset \overline{\lim}_{n \to \infty} A_n$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mathscr{A} \subset P(X)$ is an algebra over a set $X$. Let $\mu: \mathscr{A} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be an almost-measure and $\overline{\mu}: \mathscr{A}^* \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the measure generated. Let $E \in \mathscr{A}^*$ then $\overline{\mu}(E) = 0$ if and only if there is $(A_n) \subset \mathscr{A}$ such that $E \subset \overline{\lim}_{n \to \infty} A_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n) < + \infty$.

The reciprocal implication is already solved, but I'm stuck with the first one. I would appreciate any help. Here is what I've done:

For $\mu: \mathscr{A} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ an almost-measure, we can construct $\mu^*: P(X) \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ an exterior measure. I already show the following result:

Let $\mu: \mathscr{A} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be an almost-measure and $\mu^*: P(X) \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ it's generated exterior measure. Then, for every $E \in \mathscr{A}^*$ with $\mu^*(E) < + \infty$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an element $A \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $\mu^*(E \Delta A) < \epsilon$.

So, let's consider the real sequence $(\frac{1}{2^n})$. By the previous result, the is a sequence $(A_n) \subset \mathscr{A}$ such that $\mu^*(A_n \Delta E) < \frac{1}{2^n}$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is straightforward to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n) < + \infty$.

The heavy part is to show that $E \subset \overline{\lim}_{n \to \infty} A_n$. I cannot find the way to prove it completely formally. One can note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu^*(A_n \Delta E) = 0$, which means intuitively that $A_n \to E$.

However, the sequence $(A_n)$ is like an approximation of $E$ and this approximation holds both from inside and from outside. Thus, intuitively the superior limit is the outside approximation and therefore $E \subset \overline{\lim}_{n \to \infty} A_n$. But it is not formally proven... Any ideas?